# Wild Card in String Variable

Tags: power-automate

I'm trying to automate a report that I pull everyday, It has the same name minus the date which I've accounted for. the problem is, at the end of every file name there's 6 numbers that are different everyday.

I can't have the file name changed so I need to search for the file.

The files aren't on a sharepoint site so I can't use those functions. I have the connections to the server and it's working it just can't find the file because of the final numbers.

Here's what I have so far:

4 Variables setting up the current month and date
1 Variable using the date/month variables plus the file name  <<<
1 Connection getting the contents of the file from the server
1 connection using the data from the file to make a new file in another file system

The variable marked with '<<<' is the one that needs the wildcard at the end. I have it automated with AutoHotKey but that's frowned upon so I'm trying to convert it to something the Company accepts before they notice AHK. In AHK it was as simple as 'VariableName*.xlsx'

Thanks! Happy Friday!

Comment: Can you show us your flow? Where are the files? We need to know that so we know what’s possible when retrieving them. What’s an example file name?

Answer (score 0):

In Power Automate you could use expression language. You could for example use [startswith](https://aka.ms/logicexpressions#startswith) function to check if a string value starts with a certain searchtext. If it matches it would return a boolean true value.

```
startsWith('<text>', '<searchText>')
```

Try something like:

```
startswith(variables('MyVar'), 'VariableName')
```